# List Python variables that (possibly) get written/read (to determine dependencies between blocks of code)

Tags: python, refactoring

I'd like to refactor some Python code. To determine whether there are dependencies between two blocks of code, I'd like to know/track which variables possibly get changed (or actually change during one run) in a certain block of code (for example passed to functions, which might change them), and which variables are possibly being read in a subsequent block of code.

(Then I will compute the [set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of these two lists of variables, which will indicate the dependencies between these two blocks of code, and whether the order of these two blocks of code can be swapped.)

So far, I found only tools to list dependencies between modules or files rather than variables, and refactoring tips that are quite specific to certain situations rather than about general tracking of changes of variables.

Comment: The search term you're looking for is free variables (FV), but save yourself a lot of time and get an editor with refactoring capabilities (e.g. PyCharm)...

Comment: @thebjorn What menu items in those editors achieve this?

Comment: alt-ctrl-m (for extract method), alt-ctrl-v (for extract variable), or select text then right-click and choose the refactor menu.